# how to get packets log which are dropped by rp_filter=1

Tags: linux, networking, logs, routing

I do need a log of packets which are dropped by rp_filter ... how to do this logging ?

which logs how to enable.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know those are not logged. Unless somebody else proves me wrong, here's an alternate method.

What you can do instead is steps 1+2 or 1+3 below:

1. disable [*rp_filter*](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt?h=v4.19#n1150) completely.
2. use iptables' *[rpfilter](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-extensions.8#rpfilter)* match module, once with the *LOG* target for simple log, or [*NFLOG*](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-extensions.8) (or even [*NFQUEUE*](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-extensions.8#NFQUEUE) though that's not the intended usage) for full packet dump, and once with the DROP target to actually filter.

   Using *NFLOG* correctly would probably require a separate question on its own, but I can tell that even without a specialized tool, `tcpdump` can listen to a *nflog* netlink socket as if it was an interface. Usually done first with:

   ```
   # tcpdump -D
   ```

   to retrieve the correct interface index. Eg:

   [...]

   ```
   12.nflog (Linux netfilter log (NFLOG) interface)
   13.nfqueue (Linux netfilter queue (NFQUEUE) interface)
   ```

   [...]

   ```
   # tcpdump -n -i 12
   tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
   listening on nflog, link-type NFLOG (Linux netfilter log messages), capture size 262144 bytes
   ```

   You could choose to write them to a file too (`-w dump.cap`)
3. or use [*nft*](https://manpages.debian.org/nftables/nft.8)'s [*fib*](https://manpages.debian.org/nftables/nft.8#FIB_EXPRESSIONS) match for an equivalent method using (recent enough) [*nftables*](https://wiki.nftables.org/) instead of *iptables*, with some equivalent [*log*](https://manpages.debian.org/nftables/nft.8#LOG_STATEMENT) method.

Using *netfilter*'s firewalling layer is the only method for IPv6 which lacks direct support for *rp_filter* in its routing stack on Linux.

Some corner cases related to ARP or policy routing might not behave 100% identically because the filtering is probably done later.

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable the sysctl `net.ipv4.conf.default.log_martians`, then check the syslog file you should have something like:

```
[8270435.701764] ll header: 00000000: ce 47 b8 a3 39 62 de 2e 40 0c a0 0c 08 00        .G..9b..@.....
[8270435.702460] IPv4: martian source 51.247.240.165 from 10.138.86.16, on dev tap12
```